# How to convert ResultSet into Object[] and retrieve the data

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a `List<object[]> records=null;`

I am retrieving some data and storing it in to the `ResultSet`.

Now, How do I convert the `ResultSet` into this `Object[]` and return the records(retrieved values).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For whatever weird reasons you need this. Here is how:

```
List<object[]> records=new ArrayList<object[]>();
while(resultSet.next()){
    int cols = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    Object[] arr = new Object[cols];
    for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
      arr[i] = resultSet.getObject(i+1);
    }
    records.add(arr);
}
```

**My 2 cents:**

Ideally, you will have an proper object that maps Table columns to Java object fields. Instead of using an array of objects, you will set the properties to the POJO or Value Object (VO) and return the list of object. That is much simpler and makes more sense. You may want to revisit your design if you have to live on list of Object array!

Comment: you have rewrite the loop. i.e. `if (resultSet.next){int cols=... do{...}while(rs.next())`

Comment: @bestsss I do not need to. If there is no result `resultSet.next()` will return false. Your code is extra cautious for no reason.

Comment: what makes you think `resultSet.getMetaData()` is free and no recreated each time? It's not about being cautious at all.

Comment: @bestsss oh sorry,  you where pointing to one time fetching column numbers. Yeah. That's alright. Well, yes. That should be done. But I am not worried on calling getMetaData all the time for all the practical purposes.

Answer (score -1):

```
// better add performance
List<object[]> records=new LinkedList<object[]>();
// call only once
int cols = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while(resultSet.next()){
    Object[] arr = new Object[cols];
    for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
      arr[i] = resultSet.getObject(i+1);
    }
    records.add(arr);
}
```

At last you can call toArray method from Collections class to get array of Object[].

Comment: w/o  if the resultSet is empty getMetaData() mail fail, you should have it inside the loop or rewrite the loop