# How to access a JDBC ResultSet from a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jdbc

//    this is controller java file..... using Results set object..

```
 @RequestMapping("/viewalluser.htm")
    public ModelAndView viewall() throws SQLException
        {
        ModelAndView mac = new ModelAndView("show");
        Connection conn = null;

    Statement stet = null;
    String query = null;
    Connector ct = new Connector(); 
    Conn = ct.get Connection(); 
    stet =  Conn.create Statement();
    query = "select * from login";
    Result Set rs= stet.execute Query(query);
 mas.add Object("user", rs);



}
```

//   here will pass the resultset object on jsp page through spring this is show.jsp

```
<c:if test="${! empty user}">
            <c:forEach var="login" items="${user}">     
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${login.idp}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${login.name}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${login.password}"></c:out> </td>
                        <td><a href="deletecont.htm?id=${login.id}">delete</a></td>
                        <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>

                    </tr>

</c:forEach>
        </c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, [How to convert ResultSet into Object[] and retrieve the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203138). Secondly, remember about properly closing JDBC connections.

In fact both requiremenents can be achieved using [`JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) built into Spring. Have a look at methods taking [`RowMapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) as a parameter - it is much more convenient compared to the solution given in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you convert you result set inside the controller to the list of simple pojos with getters and setters. Don't forget to release statements, connections.